# Обладать талантом дипломатии, без предлога (пред дипломатиею) - можно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Перечисляются неисчислимые достоинства и умения-навыки купцов, а затем: "Не говоря уже об обширных связях и талантах дипломатии".

Вот так сам по себе талант чего-либо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Дипломатические таланты** ― это (в данном случае) дипломатические способности (они могут быть разнообразными).

**Таланты дипломатии** ― это то же самое, хотя сочетание менее привычное, но, возможно, это и к лучшему.

ДИПЛОМАТИЯ, ж. [франц. diplomatie] 1. Официальная деятельность правительства по осуществлению внешней политики государства. 2. **Разг. Тонкий расчёт, осторожность в действиях, направленных к достижению какой-л. цели.**

**Примечание**

Мы говорим: *талант к математике, математический талант*, но не говорим: *талант математики.*

И это можно объяснить: талант математики ― неясное выражение, поэтому **в определительной функции** Р.п. используется Д.п. с предлогом.

**Талант дипломатии** ― здесь родительный определительный **просматривается яснее**, так как речь идет не о конкретной науке, а об осторожности, о  способностях к тонкому расчету своих действий.

Comment: "Талант дипломатии" звучит непривычно, но поддерживаю. Говорят ведь "талант жизни", "талант любви", "талант общения". И в этих случаях зачастую лучше не скажешь.

Answer (score 3):

В толковом словаре:
[талáнт](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82), -а; **м.** [греч. tálanton - весы, вес]
**1.** Выдающаяся врождённая способность, особая природная одарённость. Удивительный, настоящий, подлинный талант. Поэтический, драматический, музыкальный талант. **Талант изобретателя, актёра, педагога**. **//** *Разг.* Способность, умение. Талант различать запахи. Талант обращаться с людьми. **Славиться талантом кулинара.**

В словаре управления:
ТАЛАНТ **к чему** / (*разг*.) **на что.** *Талант к изобретательскому делу; Талант на разные сомнительные делишки.*

Думаю, что есть три варианта: или **талант** (кого?) **дипломата**, или **талант** (к чему?) **к дипломатии**, или дипломатический талант.

Comment: Нашла одиночное: "Генрих не может разгадать, какой талант дипломатии проявляет Матильда, чтобы облегчить горечь, которую испытывает невестка". https://litra.info/book/koroleva-aliyenora-nevernaya-zhena/page-25.html

Comment: Да, я видела это предложение. Есть ещё, например: Артистка призналась, что сейчас сын зовет себя не иначе как Максим Евгеньевич и в свои четыре года уже демонстрирует талант дипломатии и харизму. https://www.goodhouse.ru/stars/news/mariya-kozhevnikova-nezhno-pozdravila-vtorogo-syna-s-dnem-rozhdeniya/#part0 Но мне все-таки кажется, что это неправильно. Мы же не говорим _талант математики или талант пения_ , мы говорим талант к математике и талант к пению.

Comment: Вот, отправляю вопросы-ответы автору: пусть думает. Спасибо за поиски.

Answer (score 1):

"...не говоря уже об обширных связях и дипломатических талантах" - вот же, и никаких неясностей. )

Comment: Смайликов в редакторе нету. Недоработка.